# SQL Error Boolean

Tags: java, sql

Buenas al momento de ejecutar me sale este mensaje de error `sql server exception An expression of non -boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expect, near 'Administrador'` este es el código

```
 public int Loing(Login log) {
        Integer resultado = 0; 
        try {
            st = conexion.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery("select * from Login Where Usuario='" + log.getUsuario() + "'"  + "and" + " Contraseña='" + log.getContraseña() + "'" + "and" + "' Tipo='" + log.getTipo() + "'");
            if (rs.next()) {
                return resultado = 1;
            } else {
                Mensajes.MD("Problemas en usuario ,contraseña y/o tipo");
                return resultado = 0;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Mensajes.MD("Se actualizaron los datos" + ex);
        }
        return resultado;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Aquí hay dos problemas:

- El primero es que estás formando una consulta concatenando cadenas sobre las que no tienes ningún control. Eso es un gran fallo en la seguridad y puede generar errores e inyección SQL.
- El segundo, es que estás enviando un valor para generar la consulta que genera una condición incorrecta y por lo tanto recibes el error de SQL Server.

Para corregir ambos problemas, lo mejor es parametrizar la consulta usando un prepareStatement.

```
 public int Loing(Login log) {
        Integer resultado = 0; 
        try {
            PreparedStatement st = conexion.prepareStatement("select * from Login Where Usuario = ? and Contraseña = ? and Tipo = ?;");
            
            st.setString(1, log.getUsuario());
            st.setString(2, log.getContraseña());
            st.setString(3, log.getTipo());
            
            rs = st.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                return resultado = 1;
            } else {
                Mensajes.MD("Problemas en usuario ,contraseña y/o tipo");
                return resultado = 0;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Mensajes.MD("Se actualizaron los datos" + ex);
        }
        return resultado;
    }
```

Comment: Me sale error en el st.SetString y rs = st.excuteQuery()